# Accessing tweets from thousands of Twitter users

Tags: twitter

I have a requirement to search the tweets (from Twitter) of a particular set of followers via the API. We were thinking of getting the followers by getting the members of a Twitter list and then getting each of their followers.

For example, https://twitter.com/TwitterUK/lists/lovetheatre-day has 325 members. The users we want to do our tweet search on is the summation of all the followers of these members.

I've done a very rough estimation (and is probably an under-estimation) in which there may be 325,000 followers across the 325 members of the above list.

So, ideally we'd like to be able to perform an API search on particular words/phrases but restrict the search to only this data-set, i.e. the 325,000 followers....

Now I've learnt about the Twitter rate limits and looked into the API search method it would seem this would take in the region of 7.5 days to accomplish!!

With Application Context:
450 (queries) * 4 (15 minutes in an hour) = 1800 queries per hour - due to rate limit

325000 (followers as estimated above) / 1800 (qph) = ~180.5 hours or 7.5 days to get all user tweets!

Is this a correct calculation? Or am I misunderstanding the rate limit? I understand there is a user context but the rate limit is lower (720 queries per hour) - is there someway an application could use multiple user contexts and split the work between them to achieve a higher rate?

I understand there is a user "from" filter in the API Search and that you could potentially use an OR operator in the query but from research people suggest any more than 2 or 3 OR operators (on users:from) results in very poor performance.

The other part of this is that we must be able to keep the data up-to-date - the above is obviously only getting historic tweets. We need a solution that will pick up current tweets as well without having to rebuild the whole data-set again!

Does anyone know if this is remotely doable or whether we might be better off looking at a certified data product instead: https://biz.twitter.com/partners/list/certified-products

Sorry for no code and generic nature of question but we haven't built anything yet. We really are just at the analysis stage of the project to determine whether it might be doable.

I'm hoping there are some Twitter API experts out there that might be able to advise how best to approach this kind of thing.

Thanks in advance,

Richard.

Comment: Hi. Not an "expert" on Twitter API... Anyhow, I don't think I have to tell you that using Twitter REST API for the task you are describing is going to be tough, not only for the times you've calculated. You will only need to do it once? And what happens if anything fails? On the other hand, I don't think it is easy to become certified either (though I am not saying that I cannot be done). How much history do you need for the followers of the members? Recent activity is ok? If it is, you're left with the streaming api... although I'd guess you've looked at it already. Good luck!

Comment: Hi. In terms of "doing it once" I was thinking we could possibly run a standalone process that would get the majority of historical tweets and save that in a DB....then possibly update this information incrementally by using the streaming API. Regarding streaming API I'm not clear as to what this returns....is it only tweets as they happen? Or can you use it to return recent, historical, data!!?

Comment: Yes, the streaming api returns the tweets only as they happen. Another issue I did not mention my previous comment, when you use the rest api you have no guarantee you are going to get the full historical record... But yes, what you are saying more or less makes sense. I am actually trying to do a similar thing. By "doing it once" I meant, however, that you've got only one shot. If you decide to store to db this and this features and afterwards you realize you are missing one...